# Auto close files in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm searching for the following feature in IntelliJ Idea IDE:

- auto close open files not used e.g. for X minutes

Is there any plugin, setting or other way to enable this?

Comment: I don't think there is such setting (don't know about third party plugins though). There is only an option to automatically close last used tabs when number of opened tabs reaches specified limit.